# How to get return value from startcmd.sh OdiStarScen

Tags: cmd, oracle-data-integrator

I am triggering scenarios by calling `startcmd.sh OdiStartscen` it executes the scenario, but I would like to know if this execution failed or successed without checking the ODI.

Is there a way to elevate return code from OdiStartScen to startcmd.sh

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it as simple as in case of any other OS command?
Once successful any OS should internally return success code (0 in linux) back to the parent process. Otherwise it would be error code (non-zero).

That means you simply need to handle 'success' and 'failure' paths in your ODI package (green and red lines). Simply put some nonsense in the `startcmd.sh OdiStartScen` call for some quick test so see if it behaves as expected in case of failures. Alternatively you may use same step for both paths (red and green) and test using [getPrevStep()](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/odi/ODIKD/odiref_reference.htm#ODIKD1237) function for errors (cf. `STATUS` property).

Two things worth mentioning:

1. This makes only sense for synchronous calls (so it waits for your Scenario to finish).
2. Why don't you use [ODIStartScen()](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/odi/ODIDG/app_tools.htm#ODIDG1345) as an ODI Tool type of package/procedure step instead? Seems lot more elegant. Same answer applies.

Comment: Actually it is not as simple as you've expected. startcmd.sh triggers the scneario waits for it to finish successful or not. Then returns success code since it has completed its task "triggering the OdiStartScen". I am not able to use startscen.sh because in that option unfortunately I am not able to select the agent. I am aware of that you may give the -AGENT_CODE as input but that does not work as expected. On the other hand by using startcmd.sh I can really select my desired agent.

Comment: If it doesn't work as expected - raise a ticked with Oracle - the only way to give us all an opportunity to work with better toolset. Switch between two methods I suggested - surely some will yield behaviour you want. If it doesn't - I suggest you update your answer with detailed steps of what you've done and what you get in both scenarios.